# What is the HDFS Location on Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to run the WordCount example in Hadoop after following some online tutorials. However what's not clear to me as where does the file get copied from our local file system to HDFS when we execute the following command.

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /host/tut/python-tutorial.pdf /usr/local/myhadoop-tmp/
```

When I executed the following command, I dont see my python-tutorial.pdf listed here on HDFS.

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

This is confusing me. I have already specified "myhadoop-tmp" directory in core-site.xml. I thought this directory will become HDFS directory for storing all the input files.

```
core-site.xml
=============
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/myhadoop-tmp</value>
    <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
```

If this is not the case where is the HDFS located on my machine ? What configuration determines the HDFS directory and where does the input file go when we copy it from local file system to HDFS ?

Comment: Did you try `hadoop fs -ls /usr/local/myhadoop-tmp/`?

Comment: Cool. That worked for me. I can see my file now. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Well, my answer answers your question, so you should accept it.

Comment: I am trying to click on the "Accept" answer link but a small popup appears and it says that "you  cannot accept an answer in 2 mins". I don't know what that means.

Comment: Just try again in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is set in the `dfs.datanode.data.dir` property, which defaults to `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data` (see details [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)).

However, in your case, the problem is that you are not using the full path *within* HDFS. Instead, do:

```
hadoop fs -ls /usr/local/myhadoop-tmp/
```

Note that, you also seem to be confusing the path within HDFS to the path in your local file system. Within HDFS, your file is in `/usr/local/myhadoop-tmp/`. In your local system (and given your configuration setting), it is under `/usr/local/myhadoop-tmp/dfs/data/`; in there, there's a directory structure and naming convention defined by HDFS, that is independent to whatever path in HDFS you decide to use. Also, it won't have the same name, since it is divided into blocks and each block is assigned a unique ID; the name of a block is something like `blk_1073741826`.

To conclude: the local path used by the datanode is NOT the same as the paths you use in HDFS. You can go into your local directory looking for files, but you should not do this, since you could mess up the HDFS metadata management. Just use the hadoop command-line tools to copy/move/read files within HDFS, using any logical path (in HDFS) that you wish to use. These paths within HDFS do not need to be tied to the paths you used in for your local datanode storage (there is no reason to or advantage of doing this).

Comment: I can see the file now, however it got stored directly under my /usr/local/myhadoop-tmp directory and not under /usr/local/myhadoop-tmp/dfs/data. I don't understand why though. This is what I see: -rw-r--r--   1 chandeln supergroup    9322974 2013-10-17 17:06 /usr/local/myhadoop-tmp/python-tutorial.pdf

Comment: So does that mean that I cannot see the file on my local file system if I go in /usr/local/myhadoop-tmp/dfs/data/ directory and execute a  ls -l command?

Comment: @user2325154 I added a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @user2325154  I am having same issue. So did you find out whether we can/can't see hdfs on our local machine?

Comment: @user1207289 please read my answer again. You can, but (1) the names are bop reserved since the files are divided into blocks, (2) it is not advisable because you could mess up with HDFS metadata, (3) there is no reason or advantage in doing this.

Comment: @cabad I see your point that in hdfs case, its only logical path and internally hdfs maintain it in its own way.