# Location of schema and data of a table in hbase

Tags: hbase, hdfs

When we create a table in hbase and insert some data in it, where exactly is the data getting stored in hdfs. I want to know where the schema of hbase table is stored in hdfs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the HDFS Location on Hadoop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437550/what-is-the-hdfs-location-on-hadoop)

Comment: That question doesn't tell about the location of hbase table's schema in hdfs

Answer (score 1):

Look for the property named `hbase.rootdir` in `conf/hbase-site.xml`

e.g. In my case, the value is as follows:

```
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hbase/store</value>
</property>
```

You'll find all your hbase data using command e.g. `hdfs dfs -ls /user/hbase/store`

Comment: @Midhun, accept the answer if it solves your problem.