# HDFS dfs full path

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

How to find full path for HDFS storage in my system?
e.g. I have /user/cloudera/ folder on hdfs storage, but what is path to the "/user/cloudera"? Are there any specific commands?
HDFS dfs -ls and HDFS dfs -ls -R return only directory list, but not path.

My question is unique, because in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437550/what-is-the-hdfs-location-on-hadoop) you don't get the HDFS path in the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the HDFS Location on Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437550/what-is-the-hdfs-location-on-hadoop)

Comment: I hope that answers your question, let me know if you have any more.

Comment: No, it doesn't answer the question, because it doesn't return the exact path outside hdfs. But the answer by tk421 in my thread is pretty awesome. At least it returns the path in the beginning of output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are an HDFS admin, you can run:

```
hdfs fsck /user/cloudera -files -blocks -locations
```

### References:

- [HDFS Commands Guide: fsck](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#fsck)
- [hdfs file actual block paths](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/44378/hdfs-file-actual-block-paths.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! It shows huge amount of info and looks like I found path